# Npgsql <-> Entity Framework Error 57014

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

i use the following code for accessing a database table:

```
 DbConnection dbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection("PORT=5432;TIMEOUT=15;POOLING=True;MINPOOLSIZE=1;MAXPOOLSIZE=20;COMMANDTIMEOUT=20;COMPATIBLE=2.2.4.3;HOST=localhost;DATABASE=postgres;USER ID=yep;PASSWORD=thisisnottherealone;-)");

 DB = new DataAccessContext(dbConnection);
 IQueryable<Customer> customers = from c in DB.Customers
                        select c;
 List<Customer> test =  customers.ToList();
 ...
```

The problem is that there is an error message: "NpgsqlException - ERROR: 57014"

The query itself takes an irritating long amount of time.

Most of the time it seems that objekts are created by EF.

Is there some possibility to speed this up and don't get the exception? (it is not an alternative to get a subset of data)

Is there something configuratable like a caching by EF?

Comment: Error 57014 query_canceled. That means you query was canceled. The question is why? How many records do have in Customers table?

Comment: @jansalawa O, I forgot some details: NPGSQL 2.2.5, EF6, 21513 row. If I use the same select statement on DB (SELECT "Extent1"."RowId", ... FROM "public"."Customers" AS "Extent1") which is triggered by EF (inner NpgsqlException is {"FEHLER: 57014: storniere Anfrage wegen Zeitüberschreitung der Anfrage"} -> meaning: stop because of timeout), the data needs 2006 ms from pgadmin3. So my qeustion is more: hjow can i tell EF to execute the query and then convert top objects instead of something which looks like execute and a very slow convert?